# Preview part of pdf in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I am currently displaying a pdf file in my webpage using an `iframe` like the following code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label class="pull-right">My PDF doc</label>
    <iframe ng-src="http://www.name.com/docId" id="preview" style="min-height:550px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

The URL returns the file and everything works fine.

However, if the file is 100 pages long, I have to load all the 100 pages. Is there a way to tell the `iframe` or to use javascript or some other technology into showing only a subset of the total amount of pages without having to create a separate file in the server with a separate URL ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [PDFJS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) has an API that can help you. It allows you to render a pdf page to a canvas.

Comment: Looks like a good solution!
Can you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDFJS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) can be a good solution for you. You can use it like this :

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {

    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {

        // Do stuff with you page

    });

});
```

and the page you get should be loaded when calling the `getPage` function.